# How can filter Kendo grid Programmatically using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following Kendo grid, I have order date as `MM/yyyy`. In the data source the orderdate is stored as `MM/dd/yyyy`.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.OrderViewModel>()    
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.OrderID).Filterable(false).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Freight).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.OrderDate).Format("{0:MM/yyyy}").Width(140);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ShipName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ShipCity).Width(150);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "Grid"))
     )
)
```

Is there anyways on calendar display Month and Year and filter the grid based the month and year selected, ignoring the date as shown in the screenshot below?

[image]

Currently it's displaying the date to select
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom filter template on that column. Below is the jquery code on how to configure a DateTimePicker to limit the selection to a year and month (This was taken from the KendoUI for JQuery demos).

```
<input id="datepicker"/>
<script>
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
    depth: "year",
    start: "year"
});
</script>
```

Another way via config would be to use a custom template for filters.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.OrderDate).Format("{0:MM/yyyy}").Width(140)
                .Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("customDateTimeFilter"));

<script type="text/javascript">
     function customDateTimeFilter(element) {
         if (element == null) return;
            element.kendoDatePicker({
               depth: "year",
               start: "year"
          });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Rose, Thank you! how can i add it as custom filter template?

Comment: @kukamuk I added one way to bind the component config with a custom template. It may need to be tweaked a bit.